# How to find the arithmetic mean per group

Tags: r, mean

```
unemp <- read_excel("/Users/wathiq/Downloads/laucntycur14.xlsx")
sub.unemp <- subset(unemp,select = c(State,countyState,Unemployment))
fl.unemp = sub.unemp[sub.unemp[,1]=="12",]
unique(fl.unemp$countyState)
fl.unemp2 <- subset(fl.unemp, select = c(countyState,Unemployment))
attach(fl.unemp)
fl.sort2 <- fl.unemp2[order(countyState), ]
```

So, I have a dataframe that 
      has the unemployment rate for each county in Florida and I want to find the average unemployment rate per county. How do I go about that?

Just to give you an idea, fl.sort2 is a dataframe with 2 columns, the name of the county and the unemployment rate. I sorted them alphabetically

```
County                ..................Unemployment
Alachua County, FL    4.3
Alachua County, FL    3.0
Alachua County, FL    2.3
Baker County, FL      4.5
Baker County, FL      4.1
```

How would I find the mean unemployment for each county?

Comment: Please, provide a reproducible example.

Comment: You could use the aggregate() function. For instance, aggregate(data$Unemployment, list(data$County), mean)

Comment: `library(dplyr); fl.unemp %>% group_by(County) %>% summarise(County_Mean = mean(Unemployment))`. The data frame does not need to be sorted for this to work. If other states are in your data frame and you want it by State and County, then, `unemp %>% group_by(State, County) %>% summarise(County_Mean = mean(Unemployment))`

Answer (score 1):

There are a bunch of options. They all give the same result.

First

```
avg.unemp <- tapply(fl.sort2$Unemployment, fl.sort2$countyState, mean, na.rm=T)
avg.unemp
```

Second

```
avg.unemp<- aggregate(Unemployment~countyState, data = fl.sort2, mean, na.rm=T)
avg.unemp
```

Third

```
library(data.table)
setDT(fl.sort2)
fl.sort2[,avg.unemp:= mean(Unemployment, na.rm=T), by=countyState]
fl.sort2 # result should be in 3rd column named "avg.unemp"
```

Feel free to skip the `na.rm=T` part if you don't have NAs.